# c++ private attribute can be used in constructor but seg faults in other methods

Tags: c++, singleton, segmentation-fault

I'm debugging some code and this is throwing me a fit.

This is a singleton class that give me seg fault on this line in the getInstance method

```
cerr << _magazineList->_magazines.size() << endl;
```

I'm doing the same thing in the constructor.

```
MagazineList* MagazineList::_magazineList = NULL;

MagazineList::MagazineList()
{
        //Initialize the vector of magazines
        _magazines.push_back(Magazine("1", "Design Times", 20.0));
        _magazines.push_back(Magazine("2", "UML News", 50.0));
        cerr << this->_magazines.size() << endl;
};

MagazineList* MagazineList::getInstance()
{
        if ( _magazineList == NULL ) {
                _magazineList == new MagazineList;
                cerr << "getInstance constructing" << endl;
                cerr << _magazineList->_magazines.size() << endl;
        }

                cerr << "getInstance returning" << endl;
        return _magazineList;
};

MagazineList::~MagazineList()
{
        //Delete magazines in magazines vector
};

...
```

.h file

```
using std::vector;

class MagazineList
{
        private:
                int _numberOfMagazines;
                vector<Magazine> _magazines;

                static MagazineList* _magazineList;
                MagazineList();
        public:
                static MagazineList* getInstance();
                ~MagazineList();

                int getNumberOfMagazines();
                void setNumberOfMagazines(int number);
                Magazine* getMagazine(string magId);

                void newMagazine();
                void removeMagazine();
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line:

```
_magazineList == new MagazineList;
```

should be:

```
_magazineList = new MagazineList;
```

Comment: ohh my, i've been staring at this forever. I can't believe I did that.  Thank you

Comment: Compilation warnings are nice, aren't they?

Comment: 2 upvotes for the question, 5 for the answer for a syntax issue. SO ceases to amaze me... nice quick answer though interjay

Answer (score 1):

`_magazineList == new MagazineList;`?